# В Webstorm не работают подсказки

Tags: webstorm, pug, emmet

Почему в Webstorm в pug-файле не работают подсказки? И можно ли emmet вместе с pug использовать?

Comment: Что за подсказки имеются в виду? Нельзя ли поподробнее, с примером кода? Emmet в pug не работает - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18099

Comment: можете как вариант сассоциировать его с html